# Batch file is not executing from php

Tags: php, batch-file, wamp

Trying to run sample batch file from php to close firefox browsers. but it doesnt close the browsers. manually if execute batch file from command prompt it is working.

closebrowsers.bat

```
tskill firefox
```

close.php

```
<?php

exec('cmd /c C:\wamp\www\fedex\closebrowsers.bat');

print "done";
?>
```

Tried with absolute path, without absolute path, escaping back slashes.

```
exec('cmd /c C:\\wamp\\www\\fedex\\closebrowsers.bat');

exec('cmd /c closebrowsers.bat');
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `tskill` you can use [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

```
<?php

print `C:\\Windows\\system32\\taskkill.exe /F /IM chrome.exe /T`;
// or event without the full path to the executable
// print `taskkill.exe /F /IM chrome.exe /T`;
// and even without the full executable name
// print `taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T`;
```

Will output something on the lines of

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 16972 (child process of PID 17912) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10200 (child process of PID 17912) has been terminated.
.... 
SUCCESS: The process with PID 16764 (child process of PID 17912) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 17912 (child process of PID 2760) has been terminated.
```

No need for a separate batch file.
**/F** - forcefully terminates a process
**/IM** - passes an image name, ex. chrome.exe
**/T** - kill child processes too

You can use `exec` instead of the backtick operators.